# Who ever reads my custom message when rejecting an edit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes we reject an edit for reasons not covered by the list given. Then I always give my reasons in the custom field. However ever since we need two approvals for an edit it happens that other users will later accept the edit without seeing my reject reason.

In the most cases this is perfectly fine but sometimes I reject an edit rather than improve it to point a new user to existing editing practise:

Examples:

- A low rep user is not yet familiar with our format style and edits terminal output as quote `>` rather than Tab indent `$`. Then I tend to explain this when rejecting rather than improving the edit as the quote marks will come back, and its rather tedious to convert them back to tab indents in many cases.
- A user just copy & pastes content to a tag wiki without giving reference to the source quoted. I feel this again is a reason to reject. I explain this shortly in the hope we will see more link to sources in the future.

Nevertheless I have the impression that my comments may not be read, be it from the original author of the edit, or from other reviewers who don't know anything about my reject or my reasons for rejecting when they had accepted an edit.

Hence my questions:

- Are our custom reject comments prominent enough to be read?
- What happens to these comments when two other reviewers accept this edit?
- How can we make them readable to other fellow reviewers?

Comment: I can read the reject notice, but only *after* making my decision. I think there are reasons for this, I just don't know them.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Probably so you aren't influenced by the comment. It makes no sense in practice, but that might be the idea behind it.

Comment: That said, I fully agree, there definitely are repeat-offenders out there and I doubt it's "noone told them or they don't care". Needs to be placed more prominently.

Comment: Maybe, there should be an option to either display to others before, to keep it hidden until after a decision, on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Then we'd probably end up with people who want to influence the reader to tag it as "read before". Or at least it's rather easy to do then.

Comment: I found this as I was searching for best practices when reviewing [this edit](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/679028) after insuring that there was nothing to indicate that the OP was actually using xfce4 as a DE and was torn between the clearly conflicts and no improvement options. I don't see that it actually causes harm so I hesitated to use that reason. However after stumbling across some clarity [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected/) I went that route.